# Win8 partitions showing up i Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Win8. The different Win8 partitions (the main partition, recovery partition and a couple of others) are showing up in Ubuntu. Now I'm wondering if they're supposed to be showing up in Ubuntu in the first place? If I try to enter (mount?) either of these partitions the following, or similar, message applies:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/jonas/Acer: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/jonas/Acer"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Anything I should worry about?

Answer (score 0):

- Bootup into `windows OS` and `restart` your pc `not shutdown`.
- Then bootup into `ubuntu os` now click on that `ntfs partition`.The ntfs partition will be mounted and you can able to see all the files in that partition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the "Fast Startup" feature in Windows:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

This feature is enabled by default, and it turns shutdown operations into suspend-to-disk operations. The result is an inability to mount shared partitions (if you're lucky) or filesystem corruption (if you're unlucky).

Comment: I see. But isn't it potentially risky that Ubuntu has access to the Win8 partitions, i.e. if I mess something up my Win8 might go south? Do you think I should disable Fast Startup even if I don't really want access, since there might be a chance of filesystem corruption?

Comment: Yes, giving any OS access to any other OS's boot partition does pose some risk from buggy drivers, user error, etc. IMHO, it's best to create a shared-data partition that does *not* hold any critical OS files. If you don't want to share any data files, you can deny Linux access to Windows by removing the NTFS-3g package or by adjusting `/etc/fstab` to block mounts. In this case, though, the EFI System Partition (ESP) will still be shared, assuming you're booting in EFI mode, so disabling Fast Startup is still advisable.

Comment: A shared-data partition sounds like a good idea. If I make one, can I deny Linux access to the other partitions? If I go for not sharing anything, how exactly do I adjust /etc/fstab to block mounts? Yes I think I'm booting in EFI mode, so I'll disable it!

Comment: Ironically, you need to create an entry in `/etc/fstab` for the partition you don't want to mount. Set it to *not* mount the partition automatically (via the `noauto` option). See [this](http://www.eglug.org/book/export/html/926) or any of many other `/etc/fstab` tutorials for details.